# How can I express such requirement using Java regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I need to check that a file contains some amounts that match a specific format:

- between 1 and 15 characters (numbers or ",")
- may contains at most one "," separator for decimals
- must at least have one number before the separator
- this amount is supposed to be in the middle of a string, bounded by alphabetical characters (but we have to exclude the malformed files).

I currently have this:

```
\d{1,15}(,\d{1,14})?
```

But it does not match with the requirement as I might catch up to 30 characters here.
Unfortunately, for some reasons that are too long to explain here, I cannot simply pick a substring or use any other java call. The match has to be in a single, java-compatible, regular expression.

Comment: It would be useful to know if you know the limits of what's being checked. It is, you have the exact string to match against a ^...$ expression, or you try to match that expression in the middle of other things...

Comment: I'm matching in the middle of other things, I'll update the question.

Comment: In that case replace `^` and `$` in my answer with `\b`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
^(?=.{1,15}$)\d+(,\d+)?$
```

- `^` start of the string
- `(?=.{1,15}$)` [positive lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups/2973609#2973609) to make sure that the total length of string is between 1 and 15
- `\d+` one or more digit(s)
- `(,\d+)?` optionally followed by a comma and more digits
- `$` end of the string (not really required as we already checked for it in the lookahead).

You might have to escape backslashes for Java: `^(?=.{1,15}$)\\d+(,\\d+)?$`

update: If you're looking for this in the middle of another string, use word boundaries `\b` instead of string boundaries (`^` and `$`).

```
\b(?=[\d,]{1,15}\b)\d+(,\d+)?\b
```

For java:

```
"\\b(?=[\\d,]{1,15}\\b)\\d+(,\\d+)?\\b"
```

More readable version:

```
"\\b(?=[0-9,]{1,15}\\b)[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?\\b"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the requirement with a missing part but was able to adapt your proposal so that it fit in the enclosing regexp. I end up with (?=[,0-9]{1,15}[a-zA-Z])\d+(,\d+)? and it works with the checks that are done previously.

Comment: @gizmo `\b` won't work if the number is immediately followed by a letter. But looks like you've already figured it out.